# Magento 2.1.5 : Add decimal number to price

Tags: magento2.1.5

How to add third decimal point to products, orders, tax, shipping price in both frontend and backend ?

Ex:

```
Product: 12.55$   ==>   12.550$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In Magento2**, there are different ways you can get this,

by
Using this code inside your view file(.phtml)

```
$this->helper('Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data')->currency(number_format(7,3),true,false);
```

This means there can be 7 digits to the left of the decimal point (7-3) and 3 to the right of the decimal point.

**OR**

> This worked in Magento 2.1: Look in

`/vendor/magento/framework/Pricing/PriceCurrencyInterface.php`

Change  `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 2;`

To `const DEFAULT_PRECISION = 3;`

**Edit For this you could go for module like [this one](https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal).**

Then flush cache.

Hope this will help.

Comment: For first solution Which files i can edit? Also, I tried the second solution, it changed the product prices  in fronend only.

Comment: You want to change the price in back-end too?

Comment: Yes, for prducts, orders, shipping ...

Comment: (i have edited my question) For this you should checkout the module for magento2.1 go for this link https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Comment: Please, Which link?

Comment: https://github.com/lillik/magento2-price-decimal

Comment: Yes, I tried it. it is nice but same problem:  it changed the product prices in fronend only.

Comment: I think this module is tend to all the prices in the store, developer of the module stated it in modules file.